# Pyspark 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'merge'

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to merge two pyspark dataframes

Here's my code:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

print(isinstance(df_test_filtered_thinfile, DataFrame))
df_thinfile_othercid = df_test_filtered_thinfile.merge(df_original, how = "left", on = "ID", lsuffix='\_left')
```

Here's the error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In\[96\], line 4
1 from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
3 print(isinstance(df_test_filtered_thinfile, DataFrame))
\----\> 4 df_thinfile_othercid = df_test_filtered_thinfile.merge(df_original, how = "left", on = "ID",  lsuffix='\_left')

File \~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py:1988, in DataFrame.__getattr__(self, name)
1978 """Returns the :class:`Column` denoted by ``name``.
1979
1980 .. versionadded:: 1.3.0
(...)
1985 \[Row(age=2), Row(age=5)\]
1986 """
1987 if name not in self.columns:
\-\> 1988     raise AttributeError(
1989         "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, name)
1990     )
1991 jc = self.\_jdf.apply(name)
1992 return Column(jc)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'merge'\`
```

I used the print statement to make sure df_test_filtered_thinfile is really a pyspark dataframe.

Comment: `merge` is pandas function.  in PySpark, it is `join`.  https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html.  also there is no `lsuffix` param, so make sure to rename it before join to avoid naming conflict.